# SQL Server: User Defined Function In Check Constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that tracks whether data has been transferred for a certain period. Here's a short example (left out a lot of columns, but this should suffice):

```
+----+--------+------------+------+
| Id | DealId |    Date    | Sent |
+----+--------+------------+------+
|  1 |      1 | 2018-01-01 |    1 |
|  2 |      1 | 2018-02-01 |    1 |
|  3 |      1 | 2018-03-01 |    0 |
|  4 |      2 | 2018-01-01 |    1 |
|  5 |      2 | 2018-02-01 |    1 |
|  6 |      2 | 2018-03-01 |    0 |
|  7 |      1 | 2018-04-01 |    0 |
+----+--------+------------+------+
```

I want to create a check constraint that prevents the insertion of the last record. It should not be allowed to have more than one Sent = 0 line per DealId.
In other words: it should not even be possible to insert a line for a DealId where Sent = 0 if there already is a Sent = 0 line for that deal.

Here's the table script with the constraint:

```
    CREATE TABLE [Mrd].[Snapshot]
    (
        [Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT [PK_Mrd_Snapshot_Id] PRIMARY KEY,
        [DealId] INT NOT NULL,
        [Date] DATETIME NOT NULL,
        [Sent] BIT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Mrd_Snapshot_Sent] DEFAULT 0,

        CONSTRAINT [CK_Mrd_Snapshot_Sent]
        CHECK ([Function].[ValidateSent]([DealId]) = 1)
)
```

Here's the function script:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [Function].[ValidateSent]
(
    @DealId INT
)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Mrd].[Snapshot] WHERE [DealId] = @DealId AND [Sent] = 0) = 0)
    BEGIN
        RETURN 1;
    END;    

    RETURN 0;
END
```

And the schema creation for quick copy paste:

```
CREATE SCHEMA [Function]
```

With this implementation in place, I can't insert any line with Sent = 0.
It throws a conflict error with the check constraint.

Any suggestions about what I'm doing wrong in the constraint or function?
Or perhaps there is a better way to do this check?

Thanks!

Comment: Try by removing default constraint from Sent column

Comment: I've tried this, maybe it would make sense if the engine for some reason inserted the default value first. But it did not work. The filtered unique index as suggested by sniperd did the trick. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am personally in favor of using unique indexes instead of a constraint for cases like this.  I have found that columns I want to be unique I probably want an index anyways, so 2 birds with 1 stone.  So I would do this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [uidx_dealid_sent] ON [dbo].[Snapshot]
(
    [dealid] ASC,
    [sent] ASC
)
WHERE ([sent]=0)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

The compound unique index does what you are looking to do: You won't be able to insert a row where a specific `dealid` and specific `sent` already exist together.  As Larnu pointed out, this should be a filtered index (for MSSQL 2008 and later).  Notice the `WHERE ([sent]=0)`, this should satisfy your requirement for only wanting to apply the rule when `sent = 0`.

Comment: I think this needs to be a filtered unique index. This `INDEX` would not allow `ID` `2` to be inserted, however, the OP hasn't said that wasn't allowed, only `ID` `7`..

Comment: whoops, you are right!  I misread the question.  I'll update.

Comment: Tested and approved, thanks a lot sniperd! I was indeed thinking about a unique index, but with my beginner's knowledge I didn't know about the ability to filter indexes yet. This will help me with lots of other cases as well, thanks again!

Comment: @J.Michiels happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, the reason you were getting the error with your code is because when a CHECK CONSTRAINT calls a function, the function code assumes that the row that is triggering the call has already been created/inserted/updated.

So in your function you are testing whether there are zero rows that have `Sent=0`.  The row being inserted COUNTS as a row in the table already, so if you only allow zero rows to have `Sent=0` then you will never be able to insert even a single row with `Sent=0`.

To do what you want, you should have only allowed one row per id to have `Sent=0`.

Comment: It's worth a lot, thanks for taking your time to explain, Tab! I like learning more and more about the SQL engine every day, and these tiny bits and peaces help me understand the processes used.