# Check constraint that calls function does not work on insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I created a constraint that prevents adding new records if it finds an inserted record has the same item, customer, type, and also, start and end dates overlapping.

I get the following error when I insert a test record into the table. Even when the table is empty I get this error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_Inventory_DateRange". The conflict occurred in database "xxx", table "dbo.Request".

More details about the table and constraint are below.

**Request table**

```
CREATE TABLE Request
(
  ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  Customer VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  Type VARCHAR(5) NULL, 
  Item VARCHAR(31) NOT NULL,
  FromDate DATE NOT NULL,
  ToDate DATE NOT NULL,
  Quantity INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT CK_Inventory_DateRange CHECK (dbo.fnQST_CheckRequestEligibility(Item, Customer, Type, FromDate, ToDate) = 1)
);
```

**Scalar Valued function**

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fnQST_CheckRequestEligibility
(
    @Item VARCHAR(31),
    @Customer VARCHAR(15),
    @Type VARCHAR(5) = NULL,
    @FromDate DATE,
    @ToDate DATE
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result INT = 1;

    IF EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT 1 FROM Request IR
    WHERE IR.Item = @Item
    AND IR.Customer = @Customer
    AND ISNULL(IR.Type, 'NULL') = ISNULL(@Type, 'NULL')
    AND (
        (IR.FromDate <= @FromDate AND IR.ToDate >= @FromDate)
        OR (IR.FromDate <= @ToDate AND IR.ToDate >= @ToDate)
        OR (@FromDate <= IR.FromDate AND @ToDate >= IR.FromDate)
        OR (@FromDate <= IR.ToDate AND @ToDate >= IR.ToDate)
        )
     )
     BEGIN
    SET @Result = 0;
     END    

    RETURN @Result;
END;
GO
```

**Test insert statement**

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Request]
           ([Customer]
           ,[Type]
           ,[Item]
           ,[FromDate]
           ,[ToDate]
           ,[Quantity])
     VALUES
           ('TestCustomer'
           ,NULL
           ,'TestItem'
           ,'2023-03-23'
           ,'2023-05-23'
           ,100)
```

**Expected result**

- `INSERT INTO [dbo].[Request]([Customer],[Type],[Item],[FromDate],[ToDate],[Quantity]) VALUES ('TestCustomer',NULL,'TestItem','2023-03-23','2023-05-23',100)` inserts into the table when the table is empty and if there is a record with same item, customer, type, and overlapping dates insert statement should fail to insert that record into the table.

**What I tried**

- calling fnQST_CheckRequestEligibility alone with same parameters which returns 1 so it should be inserting

Comment: I think the problem is that the function "sees" the row being inserted, at least it looks like it in my tests. But i haven't been able to find if this is by design or accident

Comment: an observation only: If  @FromDate is greater than IR.ToDate or @ToDate is less than IR.FromDate, there is no overlap between the date ranges. So to find overlaps you could use `NOT ((@FromDate > IR.ToDate) OR (@ToDate < IR.FromDate))`

Comment: The check constraints are validated after the row is inserted/created..the `if exists()` makes any row to conflict with itself..a `count()=/<> 1` might work as expected. Still, there could be trouble when updating more than 1/multiple rows..

Comment: @PaulMaxwell Boolean algebra tells us that's the same as `@FromDate <= IR.ToDate AND @ToDate >= IR.FromDate` which is much simpler.

Comment: Yes, the NOT is confusing. Yet: FromDate = ToDate is an overlap (the duration of that day)  if one treats "to date" as meaning the end of that day - which is arguably the most common treatment of to dates. Similarly ToDate = FromDate is an overlap.

Comment: @PaulMaxwell Correct, if you want to have exactly abutting intervals you have to change the condition to `<` `>` or in your version to `>=` `<=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary issues seem:

- The best way to compare intervals is to check the beginning of one to the end of the other, and vice versa. This requires just two `AND` comparisons.
- You need to exclude the same `ID` value, so that needs to be passed in.
- Also on SQL Server 2022 you can use the new `IS DISTINCT FROM` for null comparisons.

```sql
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM Request IR
    WHERE IR.Item = @Item
      AND IR.Customer = @Customer
      AND IR.Type IS NOT DISTINCT FROM @Type
      AND IR.ID <> @ID
      AND IR.FromDate <= @ToDate    -- do you want <= or <
      AND IR.ToDate >= @FromDate
```

---

Having said that, using a scalar function like this in a check constraint is often a bad idea from a performance perspective. A trigger might be a better way of enforcing this, as it only runs once per statement, not once per row.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER dbo.QST_CheckRequestEligibility
ON dbo.Request
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted)
    RETURN;    -- early bail-out

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM inserted i
    JOIN Request IR
       ON IR.Item = i.Item
      AND IR.Customer = i.Customer
      AND IR.Type IS NOT DISTINCT FROM i.Type
      AND IR.ID <> i.ID
      AND IR.FromDate <= i.ToDate    -- do you want <= or <
      AND IR.ToDate >= i.FromDate
)
    THROW 50001, 'You have overlapping dates', 1;
```

Do not rollback in the trigger. The `THROW` will handle that.

Comment: Yeah, good call, the CHECK function also doesn't work too well if one insert multiple rows.

Comment: @Charlieface, thanks for the explanation! Also later I found some more details about why ID needs to be passed on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50911368/6943394)